Automatically deduce actual type for base class template
I have a number of classes that each define an inner struct Result and are all derived from a Base class. I'd like to have a single implementation method in the base class that returns the derived classes Result struct when called on a derived class. The below code works, but the type duplication in the actual call to get_result bothers me.
How can I make the compiler automatically deduce the template argument to the actual get_result call?
Additional restrictions:
Currently locked to c++17, but if there is a solution with newer standard versions I'd be interested to see them as well.
Edit: Some clarifications:
Base is not just there for the get_result method, it has some properties itself and is also used for polymorphism, so it cannot be completely templated.
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    // Some virtual stuff here that prevents the whole class from being templated. All derived classes need the s

    template<typename T>
    typename T::Result get_result() const
    {
        // static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>, "Derived not derived from BaseClass");

        return T::Deserialize();
    }
};

class DerivedA
    : public Base
{
public:
    struct Result
    {
        int i = 0;
    };

    static Result Deserialize(/*In reality there is some stream argument here*/)
    {
        Result r;
        r.i = 42;
        return r;
    }
};

class DerivedB
    : public Base
{
public:
    struct Result
    {
        string s;
    };

    static Result Deserialize(/*In reality there is some stream argument here*/)
    {
        Result r;
        r.s = "Yatta";
        return r;
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        DerivedA a;
        const auto res = a.get_result<DerivedA>();
    }
    {
        DerivedB b;
        const auto res = b.get_result<decltype(b)>();
    }
    return 0;
}

Edit 2:
For now just using a free function seems to be the best solution under the circumstances:
template <class T>
typename T::Result get_result(const T& instance)
{
    return T::Deserialize();
}

const auto res = get_result(a);


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp possibly

In C++23, you can use an explicit object to deduce the type parameter based on the static type of the object this is called on: (example)
template<typename T>
typename T::Result get_result(this const T&)
//                            ^^^^
{
    return T::Deserialize();
}

Calling it is like a regular template with deduction:
const auto res = a.get_result();


Thank you, this is exactly what I would want. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KxjWx1cEM for a running example. Unfortunately c++23 is still out of reach for this project.

@ceph, I did actually put such a link in there, but in complete fairness, it looked like a documentation link, so I changed that up to be the "least surprising".

Just overload the function in the child classes:
class Base
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    typename T::Result get_result() const
    {
        // static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>, "Derived not derived from BaseClass");

        return T::Deserialize();
    }
};

class DerivedA
    : public Base
{
public:
    struct Result
    {
        int i = 0;
    };

    static Result Deserialize(/*In reality there is some stream argument here*/)
    {
        Result r;
        r.i = 42;
        return r;
    }

    Result get_result() {
        return Base::get_result<DerivedA>();
    }
};

class DerivedB
    : public Base
{
public:
    struct Result
    {
        string s;
    };

    static Result Deserialize(/*In reality there is some stream argument here*/)
    {
        Result r;
        r.s = "Yatta";
        return r;
    }

    Result get_result() {
        return Base::get_result<DerivedB>();
    }
};

That way you won't be force to send the type in user code:
{
    DerivedA a;
    const auto res = a.get_result();
}
{
    DerivedB b;
    const auto res = b.get_result();
}

Another way would be to use CRTP:
template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    typename T::Result get_result() const
    {
        // static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>, "Derived not derived from BaseClass");

        return T::Deserialize();
    }
};

class DerivedA
    : public Base<DerivedA>
{
public:
    struct Result
    {
        int i = 0;
    };

    static Result Deserialize(/*In reality there is some stream argument here*/)
    {
        Result r;
        r.i = 42;
        return r;
    }
};

class DerivedB
    : public Base<DerivedB>
{
public:
    struct Result
    {
        string s;
    };

    static Result Deserialize(/*In reality there is some stream argument here*/)
    {
        Result r;
        r.s = "Yatta";
        return r;
    }
};

In this example you can add another non template base class if you need runtime based polymorphism.

If not using templates all the get_result implementations would be exactly the same apart from the return type. So avoiding the repetition was the reason to put it in the base class in the first place. Using the override approach would defeat that purpose.

@ceph I don't think using the override approach defeats the purpose. It removes the repetition of the type on each uses of the functions, at the price of adding one in the type. There's also no logic duplicated, only one forwarding layer. I think both approach are worth it. CRTP is key close to what OP wants.
